# Removing an element with splice getting error

Tags: javascript, splice

I am solving problem in Codewars as a practice.
I have a question which asks to remove a character if it is included in a string. In my case the character is '!'.
My code is:

```js
function removeExclamationMarks(s) {
  let mark = '!';
  console.log(s);
  let removeElement = s.indexOf(mark);
  console.log(removeElement)
  let getRid = s.splice(removeElement,1)
  return getRid;
}
console.log(removeExclamationMarks('Hello!'))
```

Everything until let getRid = s.splice(removeElement,1) works.
My workflow is the following

- I set up the element I am looking for in a variable
- I check the string
- I find the place where the mark appears in the string
- I check the number
- I do splice - which breaks the code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A string is not an array, strings don't have `splice` method (because strings are immutable). A quick and dirty fix would be to convert `s` to array before splicing.

Comment: Splice need an array [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?retiredLocale=it)

Comment: You need to replace always a singol word?

Comment: Is there a specific reason, why you're not using simple [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to check where it exist of not then only perform the splice operation.

```
function removeExclamationMarks(s) {
  let mark = '!';
  return s.replaceAll(mark, '');
}
console.log(removeExclamationMarks('Hello!'))
```

Comment: string has splice method

Comment: @Teemu - Thanks for clarifying updated the answer. I was confused about array and string

Comment: Hi @murli2308 consider to use `<>` tools for create your answer

Answer (score 0):

That method work only in OP case clearly it's well for example use `String.replace`.

```js
function removeExclamationMarks(s) {
  let mark = '!';
  let removeElement = s.indexOf(mark);
  if (removeElement > -1) {
    s.splice(removeElement, 1)
  }
  return s.join('');
}
console.log(removeExclamationMarks('Hello!'.split('')));
```

What i did?

- `split` string into array
- use `indexOf` for check index of mark then check if is not `-1` (not exist)
- `splice` element and return a `join('')` version of array

Example with `String.replace`

```js
console.log('Hello!'.replace('!', ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using splice on string data type then it is wrong, I don't see any problem with your code except one missing line i.e., convert your string into an array first like this:

```
const strArr = [...s];
```

Then use splice against this `strArr` and your code will work fine.

**Note:** Change your return to `strArr.join('')` if you want to return updated string.

Comment: Have you test his code first? getRid return always `!` instead of `Hello`, so is wrong.

Comment: Read the Note section that I have mentioned already in the answer, I already knew about what getRid would return that's why I had written Note section in my answer.